# OGC WMS Validation

Tags: wms, ogc

We're trying to validate our WMS server with OGC standards,to do so OGC has a [test page](http://cite.opengeospatial.org/teamengine/) available.

Here,only stacked on a single error

```
 wms:profiles-basic-1 (View Details): Failed
```

When we look into detail
http://cite.opengeospatial.org/test_engine/wms/1.1.1/exec_summary
page requires following conditions in order to validate WMS 1.1.1 standards:

> 1. It must support image/png or image/gif for GetMap requests.
> 2. It must contain the CITE dataset in layers that are subsetable and resizable and support EPSG:4326.
> 3. The EPSG:4326 support must be precise up to the ten-thousandth of a degree.
> 4. The default style for the cite:Lakes layer must fill in the polygon with non-white pixels.

Condition 1 is clear and is supported on the system.The problem is I believe on the others (2,3,4)
What causes validation test to fail ?

Best Regards

Comment: have you loaded the CITE test data into your WMS?

Comment: I imported test layers in order into GetCapabilities XML,but still receiving the same error from the server.

Comment: I am getting the same problem with my wms server. could you please tell me how ot add cite layers in geoserver and where to find GetCapabilities xml file to implement cite layers. Please help me it is very urgent and important for me. Thanks & Regards,
Manish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer,that we should implement layers in capabilities xml.

`<Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
        <Name>citeLayers</Name>
        <Title>Cite Layers</Title>
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="-1.0" miny="-1.0" maxx="1.0" maxy="1.0" />
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-1.0" miny="-1.0" maxx="1.0" maxy="1.0" resx="-1.0" resy="-1.0" />
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:BasicPolygons</Name>
          <Title>cite:BasicPolygons</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:Bridges</Name>
          <Title>cite:Bridges</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:Buildings</Name>
          <Title>cite:Buildings</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:DividedRoutes</Name>
          <Title>cite:DividedRoutes</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:Forests</Name>
          <Title>cite:Forests</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:Lakes</Name>
          <Title>cite:Lakes</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:MapNeatline</Name>
          <Title>cite:MapNeatline</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:NamedPlaces</Name>
          <Title>cite:NamedPlaces</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:Ponds</Name>
          <Title>cite:Ponds</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:RoadSegments</Name>
          <Title>cite:RoadSegments</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
        <Layer cascaded="0" noSubsets="0" opaque="0" queryable="1">
          <Name>cite:Streams</Name>
          <Title>cite:Streams</Title>
          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        </Layer>
      </Layer>`

Therefore,I found xslt variable which returns false and validated with output xml file.

```
<xsl:variable name="VAR_STDDATA_EXISTS">
<xsl:value-of select="count(//Layer[(Title = 'cite:BasicPolygons' or    Title = 'cite:Bridges' or    Title = 'cite:Buildings' or    Title = 'cite:DividedRoutes' or    Title = 'cite:Forests' or    Title = 'cite:Lakes' or    Title = 'cite:MapNeatline' or    Title = 'cite:NamedPlaces' or    Title = 'cite:Ponds' or    Title = 'cite:RoadSegments' or    Title = 'cite:Streams')    and ancestor-or-self::Layer/SRS[contains(., 'EPSG:4326')]    and not(@noSubsets = 1)    and (not(@fixedWidth) or @fixedWidth = 0)    and (not(@fixedHeight) or @fixedHeight = 0)]) = 11   "/>
```